# How to calculate overhead of a web request?

Tags: language-agnostic

Suppose there is a fancy button to be put on a website. And the design of the button is such that parts of it can be sliced and applied as a repeating background.

I often slice the images and apply them as a repeating backgrounds this way. So one button in an image is split into several different images. I do this to reduce the size of the images used.

My team leader told me not to slice the images. If you slice a button into three parts, there would be three web requests. And this will slow down the site.

I find it hard to believe that the overhead of three requests would be more than using the entire image. So I just want to know how to calculate the amount of bytes transferred per web request.

Comment: Slice them, then sprite them. You still end up with one image, but it can still stretch to whatever width you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reuse the three images a lot in the site than you will save requests and bandwidth (your gut reaction). However the three images need to be initially retrieved -- so you must reuse them.

The crux is this: Due to [HTTP pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) the overhead is pretty much negligible (especially since you consider that this is HTTP -- a string based protocol). Three images being retrieved probably have the same latency as retrieving a single image.

-- edit: after comment from Ericlaw --

Pipelining is indeed not widely supported. However this does not mean you don't stand to gain from three images. Just make sure you reuse them **A LOT** throughout your website.

-- edit --

Browsers also open multiple connections to a server, the norm is 2 connections last I checked -- however, I believe recent browsers open more.

Comment: Only Opera does pipelining. Minimizing HTTP requests is a good strategy. Using caching and enabling connection reuse will help him.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the net tab on [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see the time taken for each web request, its also broken down into the time it takes to download each component in the response.